# What transfer mode does c++ libssh2 use?

Tags: c++, ftp, ssh

I want to use the [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org) for a project and I am curious about what mode it uses by default? Passive or active? Can this be set somewhere? Active would be not good.

Comment: sFTP (if that's what you're talking about) doesn't have active/passive modes like FTP does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file transfer uses [SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13) (as @Mat notes in comments) and, unlike FTP, is done over single socket connection, so there's no notion of "active" or "passive".

Comment: Okay, so there is no worry about some firewall trying to block the sFTP connection?

Comment: It's usually TCP port 22, same as SSH. Seeing tremendous uprise of SSH brute-force attacks I wouldn't be surprised that some networks block that on outbound. So there's always a chance that you'd be blocked. The good part is there's no some "second part" of the connection as in FTP, so you either connect to the destination or not.